# Not enough input arguments in function

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function of this form

```
    function [g] = g(i,j)
    k=1;

    if i==0
       g=0;
    elseif i==k
       g=j;
    end
```

And I don't want the second line in the code. Instead I want the function to read k from the main program. I don't want to write

```
    function [g] = g(i,j,k)
```

instead, because in this way I will have to write g as a function of i,j and k in the code of the main program. Is there another way ?

Comment: the whole reason for calling your function with `g(i,j,k)` is so that you know what your inputs to the function are, and now you want to avoid this? What good reason do you have? The alternative is you put how you got k in the main program into the function, so it can re-calculate k.

Comment: @GameOfThrows it probably makes more sense to have `k` defined in the main programme keeping the function general but it can still be tedious calling it every time. I'm going to assume it's getting called a lot of times here though otherwise adding an extra `,k` is hardly something to go out of your way avoiding.

Comment: @Dan you are right, your answer is an alternative, but I really don't see how this is less work then adding a `,k` to the function call, I mean, I would just use a replace all, but I guess it does save storage space and a byte is a byte and it is a good alternative regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function to create a [closure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Closure_(computer_programming)). Define your function as

```
function [g] = g(i,j,k)
    if i==0
       g=0;
    elseif i==k
       g=j;
    end
end
```

And then in your main script you can do something like

```
k=1;
g2 = @(i,j)g(i,j,k);
```

And now you can call `g2` the way you were calling `g` before but `k` will be `1` and it will be defined in your main script instead of in your function.

Or you could even skip `k` completely and define:

```
g1 = @(i,j)g(i,j,1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! worked perfectly. exactly what i needed.